# How to properly design a LinearLayout with TextViews on each side?

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to write a `LinearLayout` to be used as part of a `ListView` that displays two `TextViews`. One is the bank account name, and the other is the balance. I would like the account name to be on the left side of the layout and the balance to be on the right.

More specifically, I would like the balance to be right aligned, and the remaining space to the left will be used for the account name, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I've tried to use layout weights, but they don't work.

Here is the code that I have:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/accountNameTextView"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/accountBalanceTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But what happens is that both TextViews are placed together on the left side, leaving a bunch of white space to the right. How do I force the second TextView to be on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as I posted this question I found the answer. Thank you to anyone who looked into this, but the problem was that the LinearLayout width was wrap content, so it would wrap the two TextViews next to each other. By changing it to this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

I was able to use the layout weights to achieve the design I wanted.

I also changed the layout weight slightly, here is what I have:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/accountNameTextView"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/accountBalanceTextView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/accountBalanceTextView"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:id="@+id/accountNameTextView"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/accountBalanceTextView"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I had found the answer but I do appreciate your input. I did not think to use a RelativeLayout here, it would accomplish what I want a lot easier, but the design I'm going for doesn't really suggest RelativeLayout. Are there benefits to using this instead?

Comment: i think there is a slight problem in your code, as you have set the weights of those textviews one textview will always occupy 66.66% of the screen and other one will occupy the rest 33.33%,it would never be like what you wanted, and i don't think removing the weights and setting the width of the left TextView to match_parent and width of right TextView to wrap_content will solve your issue either because then i think only left TxtView will be visible,so in this case the best solution is to use a RelativeLayout where you can perfectly do things as per your current requirement, hope i helped :)

Comment: Yeah, I've changed that slightly too. See the Edit to my answer for what I actually did.

Comment: gr8, that surely will work like a charm! and moreover your solution is more elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `RelativeLayout` instead. Here is an example on how to do this in `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gcmtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But if you need to do this using `LinearLayout`, you can do something like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gcmtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any reason why you'd recommend Relative Layout? I thought Linear Layout made the most sense because all I want are two TextViews side by side.

Comment: In your case, there is no specific reason to use `RelativeLayout`. But if your `ListView` becomes a bit complex, for example if you want to display another `TextView` below the left one, your layout design will be much more complex. On the other hand, this will be quite simple in `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I also have no idea :(

Comment: Could be the third answerer trying to grab more attention to his answer. Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:weightSum=2>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="tv1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/tv2" />

</LinearLayout>
```